# Get insights/page_fans for a Facebook page from Facebook's open graph

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the number of fans that a music artist has on their Facebook page, but it's not working. I've combed through the FBAPI docs as well as SO and still nothing. Here's my code:

```
func getHolychildInfo() {
    //Make request
    let newGraphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/holychildmusic/insights/page_fans", parameters: ["period" : "lifetime", "show_description_from_api_doc" : "true", "fields": "read_insights"], httpMethod: "GET")
    newGraphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Holychild error getting insights: \(error.debugDescription)")
        } else {
            print("\nHolychild insights result:\n\n\(result)")
        }
    })
}
```

Here's my result:

```
data =     (
);
paging =     {
    next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/holychildmusic/insights/page_fans?access_token=EAAIB5k3aWEEBAHBD9lZC5AAzZAVV8K8CGBfqaxcrLdZA7oZB2Gdar8cQphXj4VciloZAnZBKp5ZA59BmGloSNz847nFqZCTVsYZCl9rrOk88OnfCnDwwADKnkOO5EUhGumEbW96riHplgfBLdnZAEYmB2Qz4ZAH1sWbuftmGKDqPft4l5QAHSZAimIyI6sOHaKWiurRK201Af6NQCXGliZBsZAUYosUHttkUbo4CQZD&fields=read_insights&format=json&include_headers=false&period=lifetime&sdk=ios&show_description_from_api_doc=true&since=1487457711&until=1487716911";
    previous = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/holychildmusic/insights/page_fans?access_token=EAAIB5k3aWEEBAHBD9lZC5AAzZAVV8K8CGBfqaxcrLdZA7oZB2Gdar8cQphXj4VciloZAnZBKp5ZA59BmGloSNz847nFqZCTVsYZCl9rrOk88OnfCnDwwADKnkOO5EUhGumEbW96riHplgfBLdnZAEYmB2Qz4ZAH1sWbuftmGKDqPft4l5QAHSZAimIyI6sOHaKWiurRK201Af6NQCXGliZBsZAUYosUHttkUbo4CQZD&fields=read_insights&format=json&include_headers=false&period=lifetime&sdk=ios&show_description_from_api_doc=true&since=1486939311&until=1487198511";
};
```

As you can see, there is nothing in the "data" part of the response. The "page_fans" insights metric is supposed to return a number - among other things - but instead returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All insights metrics besides the two public ones (page_fans_country and page_storytellers_by_country) require admin access to the page (admin user or page access token with `read_insights` permission.)

But the `fan_count` field of the page object is public, so just request that:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=holychildmusic%3Ffields%3Dfan_count&version=v2.8

Comment: Thanks @CBroe - that did it! Do you know where I can find the other public page fields for the FBAPI...couldn't find them in the docs.